# Audio not pausing in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')

    axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
        //console.log(res.data.data.playList);
        let playlists = [];
        res.data.data.playList.map((value, key) => playlists.push(new Audio(value.url)));

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { audioList: playlists, categories: res.data.data.playList }
        }, () => console.log(this.state.audioList));

    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

**I also call this in componentDidUpdate() **

The above code that I used in my ReactJS web app to retrieve data from my DB that looks something like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a2b903abcf92a362080db4f"
    },
    "name": "test",
    "playList": [
        {
            "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/a3fd5f178b7eb68b9dba4da9711f05a714efc966?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461",
            "artist": "Lil Pump",
            "songName": "D Rose",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a2c5631e54ca10eb84a0053"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/155643656a12e570e4dda20a9a24d9da765b9ac5?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461",
            "artist": "Tee Grizzley",
            "songName": "From The D To The A (feat. Lil Yachty)",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a2c5631e54ca10eb84a0054"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I retrieve the url for each songs and store it inside my state `this.state.audioList` to make a playable list.

I access each song with an index

So, `this.state.audioList[0]` would be the first song.

When I try to play this music by doing

`this.state.audioList[0].play()`, this totally works fine.

The problem is when I try to pause it.

`this.state.audioList[0].pause()` does not pause the song for some reason.

I am assuming that it is because the `this.state.audioList` is getting updated every time and the Audio object that I am trying to pause is a new object that has nothing to do with the one currently being played.

Am I right? If so, is there a solution to this issue?

Please help!

Comment: You shouldn't mix your UI with your audio model. Store a representation of your playlist "audio" part in some external module. Then you can provide an API to your UI that can interact  with your playlist. Right now, you have logic in componentDidUpdate so if you do anything that changes the props of that component, it will fetch and create a new playlist every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work in `componentWillMount` although `componentDidMount` is preferred, see : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Quoted from this link (remote endpoint being your `axios` URL here) :

> If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

But you're almost certain that won't work if you put your `axios.get()` request in `componentDidUpdate`, because this method is called each time your component has been updated and re-rendered.

From the [React Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) document, you'll see that `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` both stay in the `Mounting` section (that is, they are called only once when the components DOM element are inserted in the DOM), whereas `componentDidUpdate` is in the `Updating` section, and therefore is called each time your component's state or props are changed (what happens when your `axios.get()` promise is fulfilled).

Also, as `map` returns an array, why not assign its returned value to your `audioList` ? Here is an example that you may want to try (untested though, sorry !):

```
componentDidMount() {

  console.log('Component DID MOUNT!')

  axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
    //console.log(res.data.data.playList);

    this.setState({
      audioList: res.data.data.playList.map(value => new Audio(value.url)),
      categories: res.data.data.playList
    });

  }).catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

}
```

Hope this helps!